# angular4 local variable issue for *ngFor

Tags: angular, file-upload

I have a requirement where I have load multiple items using item list. Whenever you upload a file, upload file input has to hide and details of that file has to show like filename and other button.

I implemented the scenario by using a localvariable, it works fine with one item, but when we have multiple items, its not working. 
Assume if I have 3 itemList, if we click on 1st item fileupload button and upload a file, it loads filename and validate button, but if we do same process for 2nd item (after 1st process), after fileupload, 1st filename will be modified.

View:

```
<div id="userItemList" *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i=index">
    <div>
        <span>{{item.Id}}</span>
        <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
        <span>{{item.Count}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="UploadFile" id="fileInput" #fileInput (change)="txtUploadFile($event,i)">
        <div class="validate-file-div" #validateContent style="display:none">
            <div class="file-name" #fileName></div>
            <span id="validate-csv-button" data-program-id="0" class="button">Validate</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My component look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-programs-manager',
  templateUrl: './ProgramsManager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ProgramsManager.component.css'],
})

export class ProgramsManagerComponent implements OnInit {

    itemList = [{"Id":1,"Name":"Item1","Count":2},{"Id":2,"Name":"Item2","Count":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Item3","Count":3}];
    @ViewChild("fileInput") fileInput;
    @ViewChild("validateContent") validateContent;
    @ViewChild("fileName") fileName;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    txtUploadFile(event,index) {
        this.fileInput.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
        this.validateContent.nativeElement.style.display = "block";
        this.fileInput.nativeElement.innerHTML = event.target.files[0].name;
    }
}
```

I feel local variable is giving problem,but don't know how to fix it. can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to set itemList as a public variable ?

Comment: you have event.target.files[0].name; it's not event.target.files[index].name;? ("index", not "0")

Comment: Thanks Eliseo. But what about hide and show of the div. how can I do that. I have similar problem with that as well.

Comment: And also event.target.files[index].name doesn't work as files[0] is an array generated by event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild`

```
@ViewChildren("fileInput") fileInput : QueryList<any>;
@ViewChildren("validateContent") validateContent : QueryList<any>;
@ViewChildren("fileName") fileName : QueryList<any>;
```

And change function txtUploadFile to

```
txtUploadFile(event,index) {
    var fileInputs = this.fileInput.toArray();
    var validateContents = this.validateContent.toArray();

    fileInputs[index].nativeElement.style.display = "none";
    validateContents[index].nativeElement.style.display = "block";
    fileInputs[index].nativeElement.innerHTML = event.target.files[0].name;
}
```

Here is the link of working example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-view-children

---

Extra Notes :

> @ViewChild:
>
> You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive
>   matching the selector from the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and
>   a new child matches the selector, the property will be updated.
>
> @ViewChildren:
>
> You can use ViewChildren to get the QueryList of elements or
>   directives from the view DOM. Any time a child element is added,
>   removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes
>   observable of the query list will emit a new value.

Comment: I am getting an error as Property '_results' is private and only access
ible within class 'QueryList<T>'.

Comment: is there anyother way inorder to get data as _results is not working

Comment: @user1268130, please check demo link , it has all the code and its working 100% fine, please check that out.

Comment: I checked the link, even though it has that error, its working. But where as in my VS code is not allowing to build as _results is private

Comment: @user1268130, I have updated the method , please check now it should work

Comment: @user1268130, will you please accept and upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Eliseo is right you should get index value instead of 0. That's why. To show and hide a div, you must create a class variable like showInfo = null by default and set it with the file array value.

Change the value when the use click on the download button using `<button (click)="showInfo=item[index]"/>`
 Then in your HTML use

```
<a [class.hidden]="!showInfo">Download {{item.name}} </a>
```

which display the info if existing