# Angular5 Need function to check/uncheck mat-checkbox inside mat-table

Tags: angular, local-variables, ngfor, angular5

I can get checkboxes within the table to emit changes on check/uncheck, but  am having troubles reciprocating when clicking on map pins to toggle checkbox states.

[my table with map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBJsu.png)

Here's my table:

```
      <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Number </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let stock">
            // #myCheckbox needs to be unique
            <mat-checkbox #myCheckbox [checked] (change)="selectStock(stock, $event)"></mat-checkbox> <a href="">{{ stock.number }}</a>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="clickRow(row._id,$event)"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
```

Then from my map, when you click on a pin, run some function

```
  (click)="someFunction(myCheckbox)"
```

In my class

```
    @ViewChild('myCheckbox') private myCheckbox: MatCheckbox;

    someFunction(myCheckbox){
         if (stock.isChecked) {
            this.myCheckbox.checked = false;
            } else {
            this.myCheckbox.checked = true;
         }
    }
```

This is the example I'm working off of but it's applying the same #id to each checkbox so only the first checkbox gets toggled (I'm assuming I need unique a unique id for each checkbox?)

- [Angular mat-checkbox getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832522/angular-mat-checkbox-getelementbyid)

Comment: Is there any chance you still have your selectStock function code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more searching on the site, I was able to fix the issue using ViewChildren

- [Angular 4: setting the local variable # dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934197/angular-4-setting-the-local-variable-dynamically)
- [angular4 local variable issue for *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281156/angular4-local-variable-issue-for-ngfor)

  ```
        @ViewChildren('myCheckbox') private myCheckboxes : QueryList<any>;


        someFunction(item, index){

            let myCheckboxes = this.myCheckboxes.toArray();

            if (item.isChecked) {
                myCheckboxes[index].checked = true;
            } else {
                myCheckboxes[index].checked = false;
            }

        }
  ```

Good Stuff

Comment: go for `myCheckboxes[index].checked = item.isChecked;` , saves some lines of code :)

Comment: but this does not reflect on UI.. it still shows checked in the box

Answer (score 0):

A full, working example is following. In the class implementation TypeScript-File:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

...    

export class YourClassName implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ...

    selectables : Array<string> = ['ah','be','ce'];
    @ViewChildren('checkboxMultiple') private checkboxesMultiple : QueryList<any>;

    ...

    selectionChange( event ) : void {

        // get index from template loop or so. In this case the value
        // of the mat-checkbox is an Array with the value as first and
        // the loop index as second entry
        let index = event.source.value[1];
        let checkboxesArray = this.checkboxesMultiple.toArray();
        checkboxesArray[index].checked = false;

        // You could also loop over all checkboxes and check/uncheck
        // them based on your logic
    }
}
```

And inside your template file:

```
...

<mat-checkbox #checkboxMultiple
        *ngFor="let selectable of selectables; let i = index"
        (change)="selectionChange($event)"
        [value]="[selectable, i]">
        {{ selectable }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
</mat-checkbox>
```

I found that you have to use the toArray() method of QueryList object to get the actual array of checkboxes.